# List file in ListActivity and Delete on Click

Tags: android, listactivity

I am using this code to list the files in directory:

```
    void ListDir(File f){
     File[] files = f.listFiles();
     fileList.clear();
     for (File file : files){
      fileList.add(file.getPath());  
     }

     ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList
     = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
     setListAdapter(directoryList); 
    }
```

How to delete the file by on click? I have search about `onListItemClick`. To delete the file, I need:

```
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            file.delete();
```

How to pass the `ArrayList` to `uri`?

Comment: Wel show the on item click handler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a item click listener for list view:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {

                 File file = new File(fileList.get(position));
                 if(file.exists()){
                     file.delete();
                 }
              }

         });
```